# Finding complex roots, specifically theta

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

I'm trying to find the roots for $$(-4+4i)^{^\frac{1}{5})}$$ 
I have the formula, 
$$\sqrt[n]{z}=\sqrt[n]{r}\left(\cos\frac{\theta+2\pi k}{n}+i\sin \frac{\theta +2 \pi k}{n}\right)$$
where k=0, 1, ..., n-1.  So then, $$r=\sqrt{(-4)^2 +4^2}=\sqrt{32}$$
$$\sqrt[5]{\sqrt{32}}\left(\cos\frac{\theta+2\pi k}{5}+i\sin \frac{\theta +2 \pi k}{5}\right)$$
What I do not get is how to find theta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** $-4+4i=4\sqrt2\left(-\frac{\sqrt2}2+\frac{\sqrt2}2i\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Recall that given $z=iy$ we have for $x\neq 0$

$$\tan \theta = \frac y x \implies \begin{cases}x>0\quad\theta = \arctan \left(\frac y x\right)\\\\x<0\quad \theta = \pi +\arctan \left(\frac y x\right)\end {cases}$$

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation